# Extracting variables from text file (C)

Tags: c, file-io

I need to input four variables into a C program (Win32) from a text file. Each of the variables are on their own line.

example.txt:

```
2.651127
-7.802776
5.530998
-17.239931
```

These four variables will each be a float in my program. What is the syntax in C to pass each line to its own variable? There are only ever four numbers, each on their own line.

I previously asked this question as a C++ question; since have discovered that the solution didn't work as I am working in C.

Comment: I must say, asking for a problem solution first and *then* discovering that you're actually working on a completely different thing is not a very good omen :-)

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C? I'll be sure to avoid recommending that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) function.

Comment: yes i did. that 's' key is moves randomly around my keyboard. very irritating.